# ODI-40854: No file provided for synchronization. Use CREATE FILE <file> FROM <schema> command

Tags: xml, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to load data from XML file to an Oracle table in ODI 12c. I created physical schema(referring to the XML file) and data server for the XML file, tested the connection and it was successful. However, no dtd file is created after testing the connection although I have specified  "generate dtd" property as 'Yes'. Ignoring that, I started to create an ODI procedure with the following properties:

Technology : XML

Transaction Isolation : Driver Default

Logical schema :

Transaction : Autocommit

Command : SYNCHRONIZE ALL FROM FILE

I placed this procedure inside an ODI package and generated and ran the scenario. The scenario fails with the following error -

ODI-40854: No file provided for synchronization. Use CREATE FILE  FROM  command

Is the dtd not being generated causing the issue or anything else? Appreciate any pointers. TIA.

Comment: DTD is obsolete technology. This option is kept just for backward compatibility. It is better to use XML Schema as XSD.

Comment: I ain't sure if dtd not being generated is causing this issue. However, there is only option to generate dtd while creating a physical schema for XMl file. I don't see any provision to have XSD. If you know any, kindly help